# rearrange txt to csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, export-to-csv

i have data in txt file in the format of

**Santosh kumar**

**+92 123 1234567**

Voted For Voted
2 8 months ago

**Doc...sapna**

**+92 123 1234567**

Voted For Voted
2 8 months ago

**Ramesh Dinani**

**+92 123 1234567**

604PMO S BH: all & GD

Poll e)

Details Options Voters Settings Message

**Mk we**

**+92 242342**

Voted For Voted
4 8 months ago

**+92 123 1234567**

Voted For Voted
2 8 months ago

**Nenoram Kolhi**

**+123 1234567**
there more rough line of data between numbers like

**r SKL**

**+92 12323232**

Voted For Voted

i need data NAme and phone NUmber LIKE

Name,Number

Santosh kumar,+92 123 1234567

Nenoram Kolhi,+123 1234567

and remove all rough data my code not working properly

```
import csv

with open('File001.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split("+") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('log1.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('title', 'intro'))
        writer.writerows(lines)

#########

import pandas as pd
read_file = pd.read_csv('log1.csv',header = None,delimiter = ',')
read_file.columns = ['Name','number']
read_file.to_csv('Final1.csv', index=None)
```

Comment: I'd suggest to read the file using `file.read` ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)), splitting the string by `\n` and then every third entry of that list with different starting points. Should yield you for starting point (0): the names, (1): The phone numbers, (2) the vote results that you want to discard.

Comment: there more rough data between numbers like

r SKL
+92 12323232

 
 

604PMO S BH: all ctl & GD

� Poll e)

Details Options Voters Settings Message

 

Mk we

+92 242342

Voted For Voted

Comment: Are `Doc...sapna` and `r SKL` actual names that you want to filter? Are there any assumptions you can make about the names? How do you identify the corresponding lines with names manually (i.e. "by looking at it")?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The use of regular expressions or "regex" should be of great help in your case.

For example, this piece of code look for every phone number (a "+" followed by numbers or spaces) and the two previous lines to get the names :

```
import re

re_contact=re.compile(r"\n(.*?)\n\n(\+[\d\s]+?)\n")

for contact in re_contact.finditer(text):
    print("name=",contact.group(1))
    print("number=",contact.group(2))
    print()
```

This gives :

```
name= Santosh kumar
number= +92 123 1234567

name= Doc...sapna
number= +92 123 1234567

name= Ramesh Dinani
number= +92 123 1234567

name= Mk we
number= +92 242342

name= Voted For Voted 4 8 months ago
number= +92 123 1234567

name= r SKL
number= +92 12323232
```

As you can see, there is a phone number whithout name clearly associated in your data.